# Beego - Make use of port number from docker-compose implementaion instead using port number from app.conf

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, beego

I am trying to run the beego application using docker with the help of docker-compose. I am able access the demo application in http://localhost:8081 URL after running `docker-compose up`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/hello
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    working_dir: /go/src/hello
    command: bee run
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.10

## Install beego and the bee dev tool
RUN go get github.com/astaxie/beego && go get github.com/beego/bee
```

**app.conf** from beego framework

```
appname = hello
httpport = 8081
runmode = dev
```

How can I overwrite the `httpport`(8081) in `app.conf` using `ports`(8080) number used in `app` from `docker-compose.yml`. After running `docker-compose up` application runs in port 8081 not in 8080. How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't follow. What's stopping you from simply editing app.conf?

Comment: @Peter I don't have any problem in editing app.conf file. In PHP frameworks(Laravel) it is possible to overwrite the port in ENV file using docker-compose environment variables. So only I asked for similar setup is possible or not in beego?

Comment: To read port from env varialbles you probably should use `beego.AppConfig.Set(key, val string)` method and check if proper env variable is set and get it from `os.Getenv`. But why you wanna run it on different port inside docker? If u just wanna get access to it on different port outside (because of allready used port) you should change in you docker-compose file ports section to `"8081:8080"` then you can access your app on `8081` port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to update the `app.conf` to `8080` use the `ports` to have the docker container listen on `8081` and respond to `8080`.

Change `- "8080:8080"` to `- "8080:8081"`

First port is what the docker container will respond to and the second port is the port of the application within the container.